# when Asterisk or greater operator starts an element

Tags: jquery, css

```
*>.launch-button
{
    background:#333;
}
```

Many new jquery, css style id or class elements start with or include (>) (<) or (*), I don't know what they stand for actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `*` stands for every element.
- `>` is the immediate child of an element
- `<` doesn't, so far as I'm aware, mean anything in CSS.

To explain the selector in your question:

`*>.launch-button` selects every element of class-name equal to 'launch-button' that's an immediate-descendant of *any* element. The only way to consider this a useful selector, is to note that it will only select those elements that have a parent element. But, so far as I can tell, this will still select *every* element of class-name 'launch-button,' since the `body` tag is considered an element itself. [JS Fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sS2Dw/).

So, rather than that selector, I'd suggest just using `.launch-button`.

References:

- [CSS Selectors, W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors